# Windows(?) не видит curllib.dll

Tags: windows, c++, dll

Установил libcurl: скинул include файлы в include папку visual studio, lib файлы в lib папку, dll-ки в папку system32 windows.
Вот тестовый пример, но windows показывает ошибку, что curllib.dll отстутствует в системе, хотя он присутствует...

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <curl\curl.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"curllib.lib")

int main()
{
    CURL* curl_handle;
    CURLcode result;

    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl_handle)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.ru");
        result = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
    }
    std::system("pause");
}
```

[скриншот](http://rghost.ru/57465657.view)

Answer (score 1):

А если положить длл рядом с exe файлом?